# Flink: How to set JobManager restart strategy in HA?

Tags: high-availability, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am implementing Flink standalone cluster with HA. When I fail one Job manager, the another standby Job manager takes its position. But when I check the log of Task manager to see what is exactly happening during this switch over, I observe that, Flink makes 6 attempts to reconnect to the old Job manager(failed) with increasing timeout(500,1000,2000,4000,8000,16000)ms.

Can I reduce this number of attempts via Flink configuration file so that I can connect to new Job manager as fast as possible? What are the setting that I have to make?